# How to perform structured searches in Google Sheets API that return scalar values in C#

Tags: c#, google-sheets

I'm using the Google Sheets API from C#. How do you create structured queries that return scalar values using the c# API?

The code I'm trying looks is listed below (though I have also tried using a SpreadsheetQuery (where I can successfully implement WHERE searches). With this code, I'm always getting zero entries returned.

```
      public int MaxId(string tableName)
                {
    //Get the Worksheet
                    var worksheet = GetTable(tableName);
                    AtomLink listFeedLink = worksheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel, null);
                    ListQuery query = new ListQuery(listFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
//This line doesn't seem to get processed correctly.

                    query.Query = "select max(id)";
                    ListFeed feed = this._spreadsheetHelper._service.Query(query);
                    var entriesC = feed.Entries.Count;
                    //TODO 
                    return -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The same problem seems to exist in Java... As mentioned in Faraz's answer, you can use [Google's query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) to do database-like queries against Google spreadsheets, with the following caveats:

- the URLs are no longer `spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/tq?key=<document key>&tq=<query>`, but `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<document key>/gviz/tq?tq=<query>`
- I had problems with `IllegalArgumentException(“Trying to set foreign cookie”)` when using the new URLs – see related question [Google sites API, IllegalArgumentException("Trying to set foreign cookie") after RedirectRequiredException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702752/google-sites-api-illegalargumentexceptiontrying-to-set-foreign-cookie-after])
- the response is json embedded in javascript with a MIME type set to `application/javascript`, which isn't recognized by the API (so far as I can tell), sooo...

  - you have to create the new type and add it to the service object
  - create a parser to convert the response to the API's recognized `Feed`/`Entry` types ( a hack since the `Entry`s won't actually correspond to any cells in the worksheet ) along with some code to strip out the enclosing javascript
  - also note that other response formats are available using the `tqx=out:<output type>` parameter.  Formats I was able to get were `out:html` and `out:csv`.  `out:tsv-excel` is also documented but I couldn't get it to work.  None of these formats are recognized by the API either...

I would much prefer an official, Google-supported solution (if there is one) to coding all this up myself, so I'm awaiting a fuller answer.  If rolling your own is the only way to go, though, please point out if there's a *right way* to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Google offers query mechanism, but not the way it works for SQL.

Have a look at this: [Google Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)